# Execute foreach loop fully, though if statement get executed in loop

Tags: c#

I am using foreach loop, now what I want is this loop should run for each elements in that loop count.

Once that is finished then it should return to the function, here in this loop I have also use if statement.

But problem is when first time if statement is executing it is returning to that function without finishing whole foreach loop count.

But instead of that, it should run foreach loop fully and then return with that messages.

Below is code :

```
foreach (var field in fields.OrderBy(x => x.Sequence))
{
   if (!header.Any(x => x.Sequence == field.Sequence && x.Name == field.Name))
   {
      var colName = header.Where(x => x.Sequence == field.Sequence).Select(x => x.ExcelColName).FirstOrDefault();
      var newheaderName = header.Where(x => x.Sequence == field.Sequence).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault();
      message = string.Format("In cell {0}1, column '{1}' was expected but '{2}' was there. The Excel data will NOT be imported.", colName, field.Name, newheaderName);
      messageList.Add(message); // Here after adding all message in list, then it should return to calling function
   } else
   {

   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Move the `return null;` line after the loop. `return` implies "exit the method immediately".

Comment: But after this code also there is some more code so what happen with that code then..

Comment: Then remove that line entirely. What exactly do you have it there for? You should only use `return` when you actually want to exit the method and return a value to the caller.

Comment: You need replace `return null` with `continue`, or remove them.

Comment: Put the `return messageList` at the end of the method. Sidenote: you can improve performance much: don't filter on `Sequence` and `Name` three times per iteration. Store the result of `header.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Sequence == field.Sequence)?.ExcelColName` at the beginning of the `foreach` in a variable. Then check if it's != null and you have your newHeaderName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the return messageList at the end of the method.

Sidenote: you can improve performance much: don't filter on `Sequence` three times per iteration. Store the result of `header.Where(x => x.Sequence == field.Sequence)` at the beginning of the `foreach` in a list-variable. Then check if it contains items:

```
foreach (var field in fields.OrderBy(x => x.Sequence))
{
   var seqHeaders = header.Where(x => x.Sequence == field.Sequence).ToList();
   var matchingHeader = seqHeaders.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Name == field.Name);
   if(!seqHeaders.Any())
   {
      // you didn't handle this case
      messageList.Add($"Sequence not found '{field.Sequence}'. The Excel data will NOT be imported.");
   }
   else if (matchingHeader == null)
   {
       string colName = seqHeaders[0].ExcelColName;
       string newHeaderName = seqHeaders[0].Name;
       messageList.Add($"In cell {colName} column '{field.Name}' was expected but '{newHeaderName}' was there. The Excel data will NOT be imported.");
   } 
   else
   {
      // use matchingHeader ...
   }
}

// rest of method here ...

return messageList; // don't return null but an empty list if there were no errrors
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` is in your `foreach` loop. Bring it out of the scope of the `foreach`.

Comment: But after this code also there is some more code so what happen with that code then..

Comment: As soon as you hit the return, then your method finishes. Why are you returning `null`?
If you need to return null, then put the return at the very end of the method's code when you're expecting it to finish executing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you call your function like this.

```
CallMyFunction();
...
```

If you don't need anything to be returned from this function then use void like this.

```
public void CallMyFunction()
{
    foreach (var field in fields.OrderBy(x => x.Sequence))
    {
        if (!header.Any(x => x.Sequence == field.Sequence && x.Name == field.Name))
        {
            var colName = header.Where(x => x.Sequence == field.Sequence).Select(x => x.ExcelColName).FirstOrDefault();
            var newheaderName = header.Where(x => x.Sequence == field.Sequence).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            message = string.Format("In cell {0}1, column '{1}' was expected but '{2}' was there. The Excel data will NOT be imported.", colName, field.Name, newheaderName);
            messageList.Add(message); // Here after adding all message in list, then it should return to calling function
        } else
        {

        } // Remove entirely the return.
    }
```

That way your loop will fully run.